# Latex: How to fit 3 large double tables next to each other in the first row of the page and 3 again in the second row of the page?

Tags: tables, floats, tabularx

For awhile now I have been trying to line up tables. They are pretty large tables, but I'm trying to fit approximately 3 tables in one line. One table consists of two `tabular` environments in each other, as can be seen below. So it would be perfect to fit 6 tables per page; 3 in the first "row" next to each other and 3 in the second "row" next to each other...

This is how the tables should appear (in my case just 3 next to each other):

```
 \documentclass{article}

\def \hfillx {\hspace*{-\textwidth} \hfill}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[t]
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{r | c c c}
                $+$
                  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
                1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
                2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
                3 & 4 & 5 & 6
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tabular}{r | c c c}
                $+$
                  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
                1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
                2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
                3 & 4 & 5 & 6
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Addition}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfillx
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{r | c c c}
                $\times$
                  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
                1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
                2 & 2 & 4 & 6 \\
                3 & 3 & 6 & 9
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tabular}{r | c c c}
                $\times$
                  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
                1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
                2 & 2 & 4 & 6 \\
                3 & 3 & 6 & 9
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Multiplication}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is how my tables actually appear:

```
    \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\tiny
\centering 
  \caption{U.S. Petroleum Stocks} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ & $$-$0.990$ & $0.702$ \\ 
$1$ & $$-$1.448$ & $0.541$ \\ 
$2$ & $$-$1.888$ & $0.372$ \\ 
$3$ & $$-$1.635$ & $0.472$ \\ 
$4$ & $$-$1.439$ & $0.544$ \\ 
$5$ & $$-$0.960$ & $0.713$ \\ 
$6$ & $$-$1.081$ & $0.671$ \\ 
$7$ & $$-$0.719$ & $0.798$ \\ 
$8$ & $$-$0.732$ & $0.794$ \\ 
$9$ & $$-$0.831$ & $0.759$ \\ 
$10$ & $$-$1.044$ & $0.684$ \\ 
$11$ & $$-$1.246$ & $0.612$ \\ 
$12$ & $$-$1.847$ & $0.388$ \\ 
$13$ & $$-$1.619$ & $0.479$ \\ 
$14$ & $$-$1.697$ & $0.448$ \\ 
$15$ & $$-$1.304$ & $0.592$ \\ 
$16$ & $$-$1.052$ & $0.681$ \\ 
$17$ & $$-$0.919$ & $0.728$ \\ 
$18$ & $$-$0.698$ & $0.806$ \\ 
$19$ & $$-$0.526$ & $0.866$ \\ 
$20$ & $$-$0.473$ & $0.885$ \\ 
$21$ & $$-$0.051$ & $0.952$ \\ 
$22$ & $$-$0.041$ & $0.952$ \\ 
$23$ & $$-$0.137$ & $0.941$ \\ 
$24$ & $$-$0.498$ & $0.876$ \\ 
$25$ & $$-$0.356$ & $0.910$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ & $$-$2.176$ & $0.502$ \\ 
$1$ & $$-$2.636$ & $0.308$ \\ 
$2$ & $$-$3.156$ & $0.095$ \\ 
$3$ & $$-$2.979$ & $0.164$ \\ 
$4$ & $$-$2.914$ & $0.191$ \\ 
$5$ & $$-$2.229$ & $0.479$ \\ 
$6$ & $$-$2.407$ & $0.405$ \\ 
$7$ & $$-$1.945$ & $0.599$ \\ 
$8$ & $$-$1.997$ & $0.577$ \\ 
$9$ & $$-$2.141$ & $0.517$ \\ 
$10$ & $$-$2.400$ & $0.407$ \\ 
$11$ & $$-$2.550$ & $0.344$ \\ 
$12$ & $$-$3.560$ & $0.037$ \\ 
$13$ & $$-$3.217$ & $0.085$ \\ 
$14$ & $$-$3.138$ & $0.099$ \\ 
$15$ & $$-$2.849$ & $0.218$ \\ 
$16$ & $$-$2.639$ & $0.307$ \\ 
$17$ & $$-$2.403$ & $0.406$ \\ 
$18$ & $$-$2.349$ & $0.429$ \\ 
$19$ & $$-$2.223$ & $0.482$ \\ 
$20$ & $$-$2.257$ & $0.468$ \\ 
$21$ & $$-$1.820$ & $0.652$ \\ 
$22$ & $$-$1.837$ & $0.645$ \\ 
$23$ & $$-$1.557$ & $0.763$ \\ 
$24$ & $$-$2.217$ & $0.484$ \\ 
$25$ & $$-$2.250$ & $0.471$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
\hfill
  \caption{$\Delta log$(U.S. Petroleum Stocks)} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ & $$-$15.393$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$1$ & $$-$10.109$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$2$ & $$-$9.965$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$3$ & $$-$9.511$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$4$ & $$-$11.172$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$5$ & $$-$8.934$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$6$ & $$-$10.340$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$7$ & $$-$9.088$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$8$ & $$-$7.660$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$9$ & $$-$6.276$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$10$ & $$-$5.391$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$11$ & $$-$3.806$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$12$ & $$-$4.098$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$13$ & $$-$3.950$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$14$ & $$-$4.462$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$15$ & $$-$4.758$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$16$ & $$-$4.902$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$17$ & $$-$5.034$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$18$ & $$-$5.162$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$19$ & $$-$5.074$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$20$ & $$-$5.764$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$21$ & $$-$5.494$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$22$ & $$-$5.229$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$23$ & $$-$4.327$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$24$ & $$-$4.245$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$25$ & $$-$4.308$ & $0.010$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ & $$-$15.382$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$1$ & $$-$10.098$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$2$ & $$-$9.953$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$3$ & $$-$9.508$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$4$ & $$-$11.182$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$5$ & $$-$8.942$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$6$ & $$-$10.359$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$7$ & $$-$9.106$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$8$ & $$-$7.684$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$9$ & $$-$6.301$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$10$ & $$-$5.416$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$11$ & $$-$3.815$ & $0.018$ \\ 
$12$ & $$-$4.128$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$13$ & $$-$3.974$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$14$ & $$-$4.475$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$15$ & $$-$4.798$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$16$ & $$-$4.958$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$17$ & $$-$5.085$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$18$ & $$-$5.251$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$19$ & $$-$5.178$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$20$ & $$-$5.925$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$21$ & $$-$5.650$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$22$ & $$-$5.401$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$23$ & $$-$4.368$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$24$ & $$-$4.395$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$25$ & $$-$4.515$ & $0.010$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!p] 
\tiny
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\centering 
\caption{U.S. Petroleum Stocks} \label{foo} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc}\hline\hline
lag & ADF & p.value \\ \hline 
$0$ & $$-$0.990$ & $0.702$ \\ 
$1$ & $$-$1.448$ & $0.541$ \\ 
$2$ & $$-$1.888$ & $0.372$ \\ 
$3$ & $$-$1.635$ & $0.472$ \\ 
$4$ & $$-$1.439$ & $0.544$ \\ 
$5$ & $$-$0.960$ & $0.713$ \\ 
$6$ & $$-$1.081$ & $0.671$ \\ 
$7$ & $$-$0.719$ & $0.798$ \\ 
$8$ & $$-$0.732$ & $0.794$ \\ 
$9$ & $$-$0.831$ & $0.759$ \\ 
$10$ & $$-$1.044$ & $0.684$ \\ 
$11$ & $$-$1.246$ & $0.612$ \\ 
$12$ & $$-$1.847$ & $0.388$ \\ 
$13$ & $$-$1.619$ & $0.479$ \\ 
$14$ & $$-$1.697$ & $0.448$ \\ 
$15$ & $$-$1.304$ & $0.592$ \\ 
$16$ & $$-$1.052$ & $0.681$ \\ 
$17$ & $$-$0.919$ & $0.728$ \\ 
$18$ & $$-$0.698$ & $0.806$ \\ 
$19$ & $$-$0.526$ & $0.866$ \\ 
$20$ & $$-$0.473$ & $0.885$ \\ 
$21$ & $$-$0.051$ & $0.952$ \\ 
$22$ & $$-$0.041$ & $0.952$ \\ 
$23$ & $$-$0.137$ & $0.941$ \\ 
$24$ & $$-$0.498$ & $0.876$ \\ 
$25$ & $$-$0.356$ & $0.910$ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc}\hline\hline
lag & ADF & p.value \\ \hline 
$0$ & $$-$2.176$ & $0.502$ \\ 
$1$ & $$-$2.636$ & $0.308$ \\ 
$2$ & $$-$3.156$ & $0.095$ \\ 
$3$ & $$-$2.979$ & $0.164$ \\ 
$4$ & $$-$2.914$ & $0.191$ \\ 
$5$ & $$-$2.229$ & $0.479$ \\ 
$6$ & $$-$2.407$ & $0.405$ \\ 
$7$ & $$-$1.945$ & $0.599$ \\ 
$8$ & $$-$1.997$ & $0.577$ \\ 
$9$ & $$-$2.141$ & $0.517$ \\ 
$10$ & $$-$2.400$ & $0.407$ \\ 
$11$ & $$-$2.550$ & $0.344$ \\ 
$12$ & $$-$3.560$ & $0.037$ \\ 
$13$ & $$-$3.217$ & $0.085$ \\ 
$14$ & $$-$3.138$ & $0.099$ \\ 
$15$ & $$-$2.849$ & $0.218$ \\ 
$16$ & $$-$2.639$ & $0.307$ \\ 
$17$ & $$-$2.403$ & $0.406$ \\ 
$18$ & $$-$2.349$ & $0.429$ \\ 
$19$ & $$-$2.223$ & $0.482$ \\ 
$20$ & $$-$2.257$ & $0.468$ \\ 
$21$ & $$-$1.820$ & $0.652$ \\ 
$22$ & $$-$1.837$ & $0.645$ \\ 
$23$ & $$-$1.557$ & $0.763$ \\ 
$24$ & $$-$2.217$ & $0.484$ \\ 
$25$ & $$-$2.250$ & $0.471$ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\caption{$\Delta log$(U.S. Petroleum Stocks)}\label{bar} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc} \hline \hline 
lag & ADF & p.value \\ \hline
$0$ & $$-$15.393$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$1$ & $$-$10.109$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$2$ & $$-$9.965$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$3$ & $$-$9.511$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$4$ & $$-$11.172$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$5$ & $$-$8.934$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$6$ & $$-$10.340$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$7$ & $$-$9.088$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$8$ & $$-$7.660$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$9$ & $$-$6.276$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$10$ & $$-$5.391$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$11$ & $$-$3.806$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$12$ & $$-$4.098$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$13$ & $$-$3.950$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$14$ & $$-$4.462$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$15$ & $$-$4.758$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$16$ & $$-$4.902$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$17$ & $$-$5.034$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$18$ & $$-$5.162$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$19$ & $$-$5.074$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$20$ & $$-$5.764$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$21$ & $$-$5.494$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$22$ & $$-$5.229$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$23$ & $$-$4.327$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$24$ & $$-$4.245$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$25$ & $$-$4.308$ & $0.010$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc} \hline \hline 
lag & ADF & p.value \\ \hline 
$0$ & $$-$15.382$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$1$ & $$-$10.098$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$2$ & $$-$9.953$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$3$ & $$-$9.508$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$4$ & $$-$11.182$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$5$ & $$-$8.942$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$6$ & $$-$10.359$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$7$ & $$-$9.106$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$8$ & $$-$7.684$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$9$ & $$-$6.301$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$10$ & $$-$5.416$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$11$ & $$-$3.815$ & $0.018$ \\ 
$12$ & $$-$4.128$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$13$ & $$-$3.974$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$14$ & $$-$4.475$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$15$ & $$-$4.798$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$16$ & $$-$4.958$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$17$ & $$-$5.085$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$18$ & $$-$5.251$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$19$ & $$-$5.178$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$20$ & $$-$5.925$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$21$ & $$-$5.650$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$22$ & $$-$5.401$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$23$ & $$-$4.368$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$24$ & $$-$4.395$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$25$ & $$-$4.515$ & $0.010$ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc}\hline\hline
lag & ADF & p.value \\ \hline 
$0$ & $$-$2.176$ & $0.502$ \\ 
$1$ & $$-$2.636$ & $0.308$ \\ 
$2$ & $$-$3.156$ & $0.095$ \\ 
$3$ & $$-$2.979$ & $0.164$ \\ 
$4$ & $$-$2.914$ & $0.191$ \\ 
$5$ & $$-$2.229$ & $0.479$ \\ 
$6$ & $$-$2.407$ & $0.405$ \\ 
$7$ & $$-$1.945$ & $0.599$ \\ 
$8$ & $$-$1.997$ & $0.577$ \\ 
$9$ & $$-$2.141$ & $0.517$ \\ 
$10$ & $$-$2.400$ & $0.407$ \\ 
$11$ & $$-$2.550$ & $0.344$ \\ 
$12$ & $$-$3.560$ & $0.037$ \\ 
$13$ & $$-$3.217$ & $0.085$ \\ 
$14$ & $$-$3.138$ & $0.099$ \\ 
$15$ & $$-$2.849$ & $0.218$ \\ 
$16$ & $$-$2.639$ & $0.307$ \\ 
$17$ & $$-$2.403$ & $0.406$ \\ 
$18$ & $$-$2.349$ & $0.429$ \\ 
$19$ & $$-$2.223$ & $0.482$ \\ 
$20$ & $$-$2.257$ & $0.468$ \\ 
$21$ & $$-$1.820$ & $0.652$ \\ 
$22$ & $$-$1.837$ & $0.645$ \\ 
$23$ & $$-$1.557$ & $0.763$ \\ 
$24$ & $$-$2.217$ & $0.484$ \\ 
$25$ & $$-$2.250$ & $0.471$ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\caption{$\Delta log$(U.S. Petroleum Stocks)}\label{bar} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccc} \hline \hline 
lag & ADF & p.value \\ \hline
$0$ & $$-$15.393$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$1$ & $$-$10.109$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$2$ & $$-$9.965$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$3$ & $$-$9.511$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$4$ & $$-$11.172$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$5$ & $$-$8.934$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$6$ & $$-$10.340$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$7$ & $$-$9.088$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$8$ & $$-$7.660$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$9$ & $$-$6.276$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$10$ & $$-$5.391$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$11$ & $$-$3.806$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$12$ & $$-$4.098$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$13$ & $$-$3.950$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$14$ & $$-$4.462$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$15$ & $$-$4.758$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$16$ & $$-$4.902$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$17$ & $$-$5.034$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$18$ & $$-$5.162$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$19$ & $$-$5.074$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$20$ & $$-$5.764$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$21$ & $$-$5.494$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$22$ & $$-$5.229$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$23$ & $$-$4.327$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$24$ & $$-$4.245$ & $0.010$ \\ 
$25$ & $$-$4.308$ & $0.010$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{minipage}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Title suggests you are wanting largest possible 
2rows of 3 sets x 2 tabular x 3 column like this

[image]

I have included Sebasiano 's suggestion to alter 2nd Title

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}%[landscape] would be much easier
\geometry{margin=0.5in} %1.3cm needed to fit 3 times x 2tabular x 3column @small
% if you change \small to \tiny then above margin can be wider
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t] 
\centering
\caption{U.S. Petroleum Stocks}\label{foo} 
\label{}
\small\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-6pt}} rcc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$2.176$ &$0.502$\\
$1$ &$$-$2.636$ &$0.308$\\
$2$ &$$-$3.156$ &$0.095$\\
$3$ &$$-$2.979$ &$0.164$\\
$4$ &$$-$2.914$ &$0.191$\\
$5$ &$$-$2.229$ &$0.479$\\
$6$ &$$-$2.407$ &$0.405$\\
$7$ &$$-$1.945$ &$0.599$\\
$8$ &$$-$1.997$ &$0.577$\\
$9$ &$$-$2.141$ &$0.517$\\
$10$ &$$-$2.400$ &$0.407$\\
$11$ &$$-$2.550$ &$0.344$\\
$12$ &$$-$3.560$ &$0.037$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.217$ &$0.085$\\
$14$ &$$-$3.138$ &$0.099$\\
$15$ &$$-$2.849$ &$0.218$\\
$16$ &$$-$2.639$ &$0.307$\\
$17$ &$$-$2.403$ &$0.406$\\
$18$ &$$-$2.349$ &$0.429$\\
$19$ &$$-$2.223$ &$0.482$\\
$20$ &$$-$2.257$ &$0.468$\\
$21$ &$$-$1.820$ &$0.652$\\
$22$ &$$-$1.837$ &$0.645$\\
$23$ &$$-$1.557$ &$0.763$\\
$24$ &$$-$2.217$ &$0.484$\\
$25$ &$$-$2.250$ &$0.471$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}\hspace{1pt}\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-7pt}}rcc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$2.176$ &$0.502$\\
$1$ &$$-$2.636$ &$0.308$\\
$2$ &$$-$3.156$ &$0.095$\\
$3$ &$$-$2.979$ &$0.164$\\
$4$ &$$-$2.914$ &$0.191$\\
$5$ &$$-$2.229$ &$0.479$\\
$6$ &$$-$2.407$ &$0.405$\\
$7$ &$$-$1.945$ &$0.599$\\
$8$ &$$-$1.997$ &$0.577$\\
$9$ &$$-$2.141$ &$0.517$\\
$10$ &$$-$2.400$ &$0.407$\\
$11$ &$$-$2.550$ &$0.344$\\
$12$ &$$-$3.560$ &$0.037$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.217$ &$0.085$\\
$14$ &$$-$3.138$ &$0.099$\\
$15$ &$$-$2.849$ &$0.218$\\
$16$ &$$-$2.639$ &$0.307$\\
$17$ &$$-$2.403$ &$0.406$\\
$18$ &$$-$2.349$ &$0.429$\\
$19$ &$$-$2.223$ &$0.482$\\
$20$ &$$-$2.257$ &$0.468$\\
$21$ &$$-$1.820$ &$0.652$\\
$22$ &$$-$1.837$ &$0.645$\\
$23$ &$$-$1.557$ &$0.763$\\
$24$ &$$-$2.217$ &$0.484$\\
$25$ &$$-$2.250$ &$0.471$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
\small\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-7pt}}rcc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$2.176$ &$0.502$\\
$1$ &$$-$2.636$ &$0.308$\\
$2$ &$$-$3.156$ &$0.095$\\
$3$ &$$-$2.979$ &$0.164$\\
$4$ &$$-$2.914$ &$0.191$\\
$5$ &$$-$2.229$ &$0.479$\\
$6$ &$$-$2.407$ &$0.405$\\
$7$ &$$-$1.945$ &$0.599$\\
$8$ &$$-$1.997$ &$0.577$\\
$9$ &$$-$2.141$ &$0.517$\\
$10$ &$$-$2.400$ &$0.407$\\
$11$ &$$-$2.550$ &$0.344$\\
$12$ &$$-$3.560$ &$0.037$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.217$ &$0.085$\\
$14$ &$$-$3.138$ &$0.099$\\
$15$ &$$-$2.849$ &$0.218$\\
$16$ &$$-$2.639$ &$0.307$\\
$17$ &$$-$2.403$ &$0.406$\\
$18$ &$$-$2.349$ &$0.429$\\
$19$ &$$-$2.223$ &$0.482$\\
$20$ &$$-$2.257$ &$0.468$\\
$21$ &$$-$1.820$ &$0.652$\\
$22$ &$$-$1.837$ &$0.645$\\
$23$ &$$-$1.557$ &$0.763$\\
$24$ &$$-$2.217$ &$0.484$\\
$25$ &$$-$2.250$ &$0.471$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}\hspace{1pt}\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-7pt}}rcc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$2.176$ &$0.502$\\
$1$ &$$-$2.636$ &$0.308$\\
$2$ &$$-$3.156$ &$0.095$\\
$3$ &$$-$2.979$ &$0.164$\\
$4$ &$$-$2.914$ &$0.191$\\
$5$ &$$-$2.229$ &$0.479$\\
$6$ &$$-$2.407$ &$0.405$\\
$7$ &$$-$1.945$ &$0.599$\\
$8$ &$$-$1.997$ &$0.577$\\
$9$ &$$-$2.141$ &$0.517$\\
$10$ &$$-$2.400$ &$0.407$\\
$11$ &$$-$2.550$ &$0.344$\\
$12$ &$$-$3.560$ &$0.037$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.217$ &$0.085$\\
$14$ &$$-$3.138$ &$0.099$\\
$15$ &$$-$2.849$ &$0.218$\\
$16$ &$$-$2.639$ &$0.307$\\
$17$ &$$-$2.403$ &$0.406$\\
$18$ &$$-$2.349$ &$0.429$\\
$19$ &$$-$2.223$ &$0.482$\\
$20$ &$$-$2.257$ &$0.468$\\
$21$ &$$-$1.820$ &$0.652$\\
$22$ &$$-$1.837$ &$0.645$\\
$23$ &$$-$1.557$ &$0.763$\\
$24$ &$$-$2.217$ &$0.484$\\
$25$ &$$-$2.250$ &$0.471$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
\small\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-7pt}} rcc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$2.176$ &$0.502$\\
$1$ &$$-$2.636$ &$0.308$\\
$2$ &$$-$3.156$ &$0.095$\\
$3$ &$$-$2.979$ &$0.164$\\
$4$ &$$-$2.914$ &$0.191$\\
$5$ &$$-$2.229$ &$0.479$\\
$6$ &$$-$2.407$ &$0.405$\\
$7$ &$$-$1.945$ &$0.599$\\
$8$ &$$-$1.997$ &$0.577$\\
$9$ &$$-$2.141$ &$0.517$\\
$10$ &$$-$2.400$ &$0.407$\\
$11$ &$$-$2.550$ &$0.344$\\
$12$ &$$-$3.560$ &$0.037$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.217$ &$0.085$\\
$14$ &$$-$3.138$ &$0.099$\\
$15$ &$$-$2.849$ &$0.218$\\
$16$ &$$-$2.639$ &$0.307$\\
$17$ &$$-$2.403$ &$0.406$\\
$18$ &$$-$2.349$ &$0.429$\\
$19$ &$$-$2.223$ &$0.482$\\
$20$ &$$-$2.257$ &$0.468$\\
$21$ &$$-$1.820$ &$0.652$\\
$22$ &$$-$1.837$ &$0.645$\\
$23$ &$$-$1.557$ &$0.763$\\
$24$ &$$-$2.217$ &$0.484$\\
$25$ &$$-$2.250$ &$0.471$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}\hspace{1pt}\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-7pt}}rcc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$2.176$ &$0.502$\\
$1$ &$$-$2.636$ &$0.308$\\
$2$ &$$-$3.156$ &$0.095$\\
$3$ &$$-$2.979$ &$0.164$\\
$4$ &$$-$2.914$ &$0.191$\\
$5$ &$$-$2.229$ &$0.479$\\
$6$ &$$-$2.407$ &$0.405$\\
$7$ &$$-$1.945$ &$0.599$\\
$8$ &$$-$1.997$ &$0.577$\\
$9$ &$$-$2.141$ &$0.517$\\
$10$ &$$-$2.400$ &$0.407$\\
$11$ &$$-$2.550$ &$0.344$\\
$12$ &$$-$3.560$ &$0.037$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.217$ &$0.085$\\
$14$ &$$-$3.138$ &$0.099$\\
$15$ &$$-$2.849$ &$0.218$\\
$16$ &$$-$2.639$ &$0.307$\\
$17$ &$$-$2.403$ &$0.406$\\
$18$ &$$-$2.349$ &$0.429$\\
$19$ &$$-$2.223$ &$0.482$\\
$20$ &$$-$2.257$ &$0.468$\\
$21$ &$$-$1.820$ &$0.652$\\
$22$ &$$-$1.837$ &$0.645$\\
$23$ &$$-$1.557$ &$0.763$\\
$24$ &$$-$2.217$ &$0.484$\\
$25$ &$$-$2.250$ &$0.471$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%<=====================================split
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{$\Delta \log$ (U.S. Petroleum Stocks)}\label{bar} 
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-7pt}} rcc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$15.382$ &$0.010$\\
$1$ &$$-$10.098$ &$0.010$\\
$2$ &$$-$9.953$ &$0.010$\\
$3$ &$$-$9.508$ &$0.010$\\
$4$ &$$-$11.182$ &$0.010$\\
$5$ &$$-$8.942$ &$0.010$\\
$6$ &$$-$10.359$ &$0.010$\\
$7$ &$$-$9.106$ &$0.010$\\
$8$ &$$-$7.684$ &$0.010$\\
$9$ &$$-$6.301$ &$0.010$\\
$10$ &$$-$5.416$ &$0.010$\\
$11$ &$$-$3.815$ &$0.018$\\
$12$ &$$-$4.128$ &$0.010$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.974$ &$0.010$\\
$14$ &$$-$4.475$ &$0.010$\\
$15$ &$$-$4.798$ &$0.010$\\
$16$ &$$-$4.958$ &$0.010$\\
$17$ &$$-$5.085$ &$0.010$\\
$18$ &$$-$5.251$ &$0.010$\\
$19$ &$$-$5.178$ &$0.010$\\
$20$ &$$-$5.925$ &$0.010$\\
$21$ &$$-$5.650$ &$0.010$\\
$22$ &$$-$5.401$ &$0.010$\\
$23$ &$$-$4.368$ &$0.010$\\
$24$ &$$-$4.395$ &$0.010$\\
$25$ &$$-$4.515$ &$0.010$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}\hspace{1pt}\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-7pt}}rcc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$15.382$ &$0.010$\\
$1$ &$$-$10.098$ &$0.010$\\
$2$ &$$-$9.953$ &$0.010$\\
$3$ &$$-$9.508$ &$0.010$\\
$4$ &$$-$11.182$ &$0.010$\\
$5$ &$$-$8.942$ &$0.010$\\
$6$ &$$-$10.359$ &$0.010$\\
$7$ &$$-$9.106$ &$0.010$\\
$8$ &$$-$7.684$ &$0.010$\\
$9$ &$$-$6.301$ &$0.010$\\
$10$ &$$-$5.416$ &$0.010$\\
$11$ &$$-$3.815$ &$0.018$\\
$12$ &$$-$4.128$ &$0.010$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.974$ &$0.010$\\
$14$ &$$-$4.475$ &$0.010$\\
$15$ &$$-$4.798$ &$0.010$\\
$16$ &$$-$4.958$ &$0.010$\\
$17$ &$$-$5.085$ &$0.010$\\
$18$ &$$-$5.251$ &$0.010$\\
$19$ &$$-$5.178$ &$0.010$\\
$20$ &$$-$5.925$ &$0.010$\\
$21$ &$$-$5.650$ &$0.010$\\
$22$ &$$-$5.401$ &$0.010$\\
$23$ &$$-$4.368$ &$0.010$\\
$24$ &$$-$4.395$ &$0.010$\\
$25$ &$$-$4.515$ &$0.010$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
\small\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-7pt}}rcc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$15.382$ &$0.010$\\
$1$ &$$-$10.098$ &$0.010$\\
$2$ &$$-$9.953$ &$0.010$\\
$3$ &$$-$9.508$ &$0.010$\\
$4$ &$$-$11.182$ &$0.010$\\
$5$ &$$-$8.942$ &$0.010$\\
$6$ &$$-$10.359$ &$0.010$\\
$7$ &$$-$9.106$ &$0.010$\\
$8$ &$$-$7.684$ &$0.010$\\
$9$ &$$-$6.301$ &$0.010$\\
$10$ &$$-$5.416$ &$0.010$\\
$11$ &$$-$3.815$ &$0.018$\\
$12$ &$$-$4.128$ &$0.010$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.974$ &$0.010$\\
$14$ &$$-$4.475$ &$0.010$\\
$15$ &$$-$4.798$ &$0.010$\\
$16$ &$$-$4.958$ &$0.010$\\
$17$ &$$-$5.085$ &$0.010$\\
$18$ &$$-$5.251$ &$0.010$\\
$19$ &$$-$5.178$ &$0.010$\\
$20$ &$$-$5.925$ &$0.010$\\
$21$ &$$-$5.650$ &$0.010$\\
$22$ &$$-$5.401$ &$0.010$\\
$23$ &$$-$4.368$ &$0.010$\\
$24$ &$$-$4.395$ &$0.010$\\
$25$ &$$-$4.515$ &$0.010$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}\hspace{1pt}\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-7pt}}rcc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$15.382$ &$0.010$\\
$1$ &$$-$10.098$ &$0.010$\\
$2$ &$$-$9.953$ &$0.010$\\
$3$ &$$-$9.508$ &$0.010$\\
$4$ &$$-$11.182$ &$0.010$\\
$5$ &$$-$8.942$ &$0.010$\\
$6$ &$$-$10.359$ &$0.010$\\
$7$ &$$-$9.106$ &$0.010$\\
$8$ &$$-$7.684$ &$0.010$\\
$9$ &$$-$6.301$ &$0.010$\\
$10$ &$$-$5.416$ &$0.010$\\
$11$ &$$-$3.815$ &$0.018$\\
$12$ &$$-$4.128$ &$0.010$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.974$ &$0.010$\\
$14$ &$$-$4.475$ &$0.010$\\
$15$ &$$-$4.798$ &$0.010$\\
$16$ &$$-$4.958$ &$0.010$\\
$17$ &$$-$5.085$ &$0.010$\\
$18$ &$$-$5.251$ &$0.010$\\
$19$ &$$-$5.178$ &$0.010$\\
$20$ &$$-$5.925$ &$0.010$\\
$21$ &$$-$5.650$ &$0.010$\\
$22$ &$$-$5.401$ &$0.010$\\
$23$ &$$-$4.368$ &$0.010$\\
$24$ &$$-$4.395$ &$0.010$\\
$25$ &$$-$4.515$ &$0.010$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
\small\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-7pt}} rcc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$15.382$ &$0.010$\\
$1$ &$$-$10.098$ &$0.010$\\
$2$ &$$-$9.953$ &$0.010$\\
$3$ &$$-$9.508$ &$0.010$\\
$4$ &$$-$11.182$ &$0.010$\\
$5$ &$$-$8.942$ &$0.010$\\
$6$ &$$-$10.359$ &$0.010$\\
$7$ &$$-$9.106$ &$0.010$\\
$8$ &$$-$7.684$ &$0.010$\\
$9$ &$$-$6.301$ &$0.010$\\
$10$ &$$-$5.416$ &$0.010$\\
$11$ &$$-$3.815$ &$0.018$\\
$12$ &$$-$4.128$ &$0.010$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.974$ &$0.010$\\
$14$ &$$-$4.475$ &$0.010$\\
$15$ &$$-$4.798$ &$0.010$\\
$16$ &$$-$4.958$ &$0.010$\\
$17$ &$$-$5.085$ &$0.010$\\
$18$ &$$-$5.251$ &$0.010$\\
$19$ &$$-$5.178$ &$0.010$\\
$20$ &$$-$5.925$ &$0.010$\\
$21$ &$$-$5.650$ &$0.010$\\
$22$ &$$-$5.401$ &$0.010$\\
$23$ &$$-$4.368$ &$0.010$\\
$24$ &$$-$4.395$ &$0.010$\\
$25$ &$$-$4.515$ &$0.010$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}\hspace{1pt}\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{-7pt}}rcc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
lag & ADF & p.value\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
$0$ &$$-$15.382$ &$0.010$\\
$1$ &$$-$10.098$ &$0.010$\\
$2$ &$$-$9.953$ &$0.010$\\
$3$ &$$-$9.508$ &$0.010$\\
$4$ &$$-$11.182$ &$0.010$\\
$5$ &$$-$8.942$ &$0.010$\\
$6$ &$$-$10.359$ &$0.010$\\
$7$ &$$-$9.106$ &$0.010$\\
$8$ &$$-$7.684$ &$0.010$\\
$9$ &$$-$6.301$ &$0.010$\\
$10$ &$$-$5.416$ &$0.010$\\
$11$ &$$-$3.815$ &$0.018$\\
$12$ &$$-$4.128$ &$0.010$\\
$13$ &$$-$3.974$ &$0.010$\\
$14$ &$$-$4.475$ &$0.010$\\
$15$ &$$-$4.798$ &$0.010$\\
$16$ &$$-$4.958$ &$0.010$\\
$17$ &$$-$5.085$ &$0.010$\\
$18$ &$$-$5.251$ &$0.010$\\
$19$ &$$-$5.178$ &$0.010$\\
$20$ &$$-$5.925$ &$0.010$\\
$21$ &$$-$5.650$ &$0.010$\\
$22$ &$$-$5.401$ &$0.010$\\
$23$ &$$-$4.368$ &$0.010$\\
$24$ &$$-$4.395$ &$0.010$\\
$25$ &$$-$4.515$ &$0.010$\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: There is into a original code a bad `$\Delta log$`. Is it better `$\Delta \log$` instead of `$\Delta log$`?

Comment: You're always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You're mentioning three tabulars, but show just two, so I repeated the second table in each case.

You can get alignment of top and bottom tables, with also alignment at the decimal period, using `siunitx`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\scriptsize
\centering 

\caption{U.S. Petroleum Stocks}\label{uspetrstock}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=-2.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  @{}
}
\toprule
{lag} & {ADF} & {$p$ value} \\ 
\midrule
0 & -0.990 & 0.702 \\ 
1 & -1.448 & 0.541 \\ 
2 & -1.888 & 0.372 \\ 
3 & -1.635 & 0.472 \\ 
4 & -1.439 & 0.544 \\ 
5 & -0.960 & 0.713 \\ 
6 & -1.081 & 0.671 \\ 
7 & -0.719 & 0.798 \\ 
8 & -0.732 & 0.794 \\ 
9 & -0.831 & 0.759 \\ 
10 & -1.044 & 0.684 \\ 
11 & -1.246 & 0.612 \\ 
12 & -1.847 & 0.388 \\ 
13 & -1.619 & 0.479 \\ 
14 & -1.697 & 0.448 \\ 
15 & -1.304 & 0.592 \\ 
16 & -1.052 & 0.681 \\ 
17 & -0.919 & 0.728 \\ 
18 & -0.698 & 0.806 \\ 
19 & -0.526 & 0.866 \\ 
20 & -0.473 & 0.885 \\ 
21 & -0.051 & 0.952 \\ 
22 & -0.041 & 0.952 \\ 
23 & -0.137 & 0.941 \\ 
24 & -0.498 & 0.876 \\ 
25 & -0.356 & 0.910 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=-2.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  @{}
}
\toprule
{lag} & {ADF} & {$p$ value} \\
\midrule
0 & -2.176 & 0.502 \\ 
1 & -2.636 & 0.308 \\ 
2 & -3.156 & 0.095 \\ 
3 & -2.979 & 0.164 \\ 
4 & -2.914 & 0.191 \\ 
5 & -2.229 & 0.479 \\ 
6 & -2.407 & 0.405 \\ 
7 & -1.945 & 0.599 \\ 
8 & -1.997 & 0.577 \\ 
9 & -2.141 & 0.517 \\ 
10 & -2.400 & 0.407 \\ 
11 & -2.550 & 0.344 \\ 
12 & -3.560 & 0.037 \\ 
13 & -3.217 & 0.085 \\ 
14 & -3.138 & 0.099 \\ 
15 & -2.849 & 0.218 \\ 
16 & -2.639 & 0.307 \\ 
17 & -2.403 & 0.406 \\ 
18 & -2.349 & 0.429 \\ 
19 & -2.223 & 0.482 \\ 
20 & -2.257 & 0.468 \\ 
21 & -1.820 & 0.652 \\ 
22 & -1.837 & 0.645 \\ 
23 & -1.557 & 0.763 \\ 
24 & -2.217 & 0.484 \\ 
25 & -2.250 & 0.471 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=-2.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  @{}
}
\toprule
{lag} & {ADF} & {$p$ value} \\
\midrule
0 & -2.176 & 0.502 \\ 
1 & -2.636 & 0.308 \\ 
2 & -3.156 & 0.095 \\ 
3 & -2.979 & 0.164 \\ 
4 & -2.914 & 0.191 \\ 
5 & -2.229 & 0.479 \\ 
6 & -2.407 & 0.405 \\ 
7 & -1.945 & 0.599 \\ 
8 & -1.997 & 0.577 \\ 
9 & -2.141 & 0.517 \\ 
10 & -2.400 & 0.407 \\ 
11 & -2.550 & 0.344 \\ 
12 & -3.560 & 0.037 \\ 
13 & -3.217 & 0.085 \\ 
14 & -3.138 & 0.099 \\ 
15 & -2.849 & 0.218 \\ 
16 & -2.639 & 0.307 \\ 
17 & -2.403 & 0.406 \\ 
18 & -2.349 & 0.429 \\ 
19 & -2.223 & 0.482 \\ 
20 & -2.257 & 0.468 \\ 
21 & -1.820 & 0.652 \\ 
22 & -1.837 & 0.645 \\ 
23 & -1.557 & 0.763 \\ 
24 & -2.217 & 0.484 \\ 
25 & -2.250 & 0.471 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\caption{$\Delta\log$(U.S. Petroleum Stocks)}\label{deltauspetrstock} 

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=-2.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  @{}
}
\toprule
{lag} & {ADF} & {$p$ value} \\ 
\midrule
0 & -15.393 & 0.010 \\ 
1 & -10.109 & 0.010 \\ 
2 & -9.965 & 0.010 \\ 
3 & -9.511 & 0.010 \\ 
4 & -11.172 & 0.010 \\ 
5 & -8.934 & 0.010 \\ 
6 & -10.340 & 0.010 \\ 
7 & -9.088 & 0.010 \\ 
8 & -7.660 & 0.010 \\ 
9 & -6.276 & 0.010 \\ 
10 & -5.391 & 0.010 \\ 
11 & -3.806 & 0.010 \\ 
12 & -4.098 & 0.010 \\ 
13 & -3.950 & 0.010 \\ 
14 & -4.462 & 0.010 \\ 
15 & -4.758 & 0.010 \\ 
16 & -4.902 & 0.010 \\ 
17 & -5.034 & 0.010 \\ 
18 & -5.162 & 0.010 \\ 
19 & -5.074 & 0.010 \\ 
20 & -5.764 & 0.010 \\ 
21 & -5.494 & 0.010 \\ 
22 & -5.229 & 0.010 \\ 
23 & -4.327 & 0.010 \\ 
24 & -4.245 & 0.010 \\ 
25 & -4.308 & 0.010 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=-2.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  @{}
}
\toprule
{lag} & {ADF} & {$p$ value} \\ 
\midrule
0 & -15.382 & 0.010 \\ 
1 & -10.098 & 0.010 \\ 
2 & -9.953 & 0.010 \\ 
3 & -9.508 & 0.010 \\ 
4 & -11.182 & 0.010 \\ 
5 & -8.942 & 0.010 \\ 
6 & -10.359 & 0.010 \\ 
7 & -9.106 & 0.010 \\ 
8 & -7.684 & 0.010 \\ 
9 & -6.301 & 0.010 \\ 
10 & -5.416 & 0.010 \\ 
11 & -3.815 & 0.018 \\ 
12 & -4.128 & 0.010 \\ 
13 & -3.974 & 0.010 \\ 
14 & -4.475 & 0.010 \\ 
15 & -4.798 & 0.010 \\ 
16 & -4.958 & 0.010 \\ 
17 & -5.085 & 0.010 \\ 
18 & -5.251 & 0.010 \\ 
19 & -5.178 & 0.010 \\ 
20 & -5.925 & 0.010 \\ 
21 & -5.650 & 0.010 \\ 
22 & -5.401 & 0.010 \\ 
23 & -4.368 & 0.010 \\ 
24 & -4.395 & 0.010 \\ 
25 & -4.515 & 0.010 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=-2.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  @{}
}
\toprule
{lag} & {ADF} & {$p$ value} \\ 
\midrule
0 & -15.382 & 0.010 \\ 
1 & -10.098 & 0.010 \\ 
2 & -9.953 & 0.010 \\ 
3 & -9.508 & 0.010 \\ 
4 & -11.182 & 0.010 \\ 
5 & -8.942 & 0.010 \\ 
6 & -10.359 & 0.010 \\ 
7 & -9.106 & 0.010 \\ 
8 & -7.684 & 0.010 \\ 
9 & -6.301 & 0.010 \\ 
10 & -5.416 & 0.010 \\ 
11 & -3.815 & 0.018 \\ 
12 & -4.128 & 0.010 \\ 
13 & -3.974 & 0.010 \\ 
14 & -4.475 & 0.010 \\ 
15 & -4.798 & 0.010 \\ 
16 & -4.958 & 0.010 \\ 
17 & -5.085 & 0.010 \\ 
18 & -5.251 & 0.010 \\ 
19 & -5.178 & 0.010 \\ 
20 & -5.925 & 0.010 \\ 
21 & -5.650 & 0.010 \\ 
22 & -5.401 & 0.010 \\ 
23 & -4.368 & 0.010 \\ 
24 & -4.395 & 0.010 \\ 
25 & -4.515 & 0.010 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]